# Deleting a big amont of files from a specific list of file names (python)

Tags: python

I need to delete a large amount of files from a list with their names (I need to delete 2450 files from a total of 10015 files). But the code I'm using, though it works, is too time-consuming to do the job. It's definitely not optimized to get the job done faster.
Anyone have a better idea to deal with this problem?

```
os.chdir(directoryPath)
for filename in os.listdir('D:\Python\Jupyter\IP_Project\DataBase'):
    for pattern in ['ISIC_0024396*', 'ISIC_0024630*', 'ISIC_0024672*', 
                    'ISIC_0024700*', 'ISIC_0024771*', 'ISIC_0024834*', 
                    'ISIC_0024869*', 'ISIC_0024918*', 'ISIC_0024962*', 
                    'ISIC_0024998*', 'ISIC_0025005*', 'ISIC_0025040*', 
                    'ISIC_0025046*', 'ISIC_0025064*', 'ISIC_0025073*', 
                    'ISIC_0025112*', 'ISIC_0025152*', 'ISIC_0025168*', 
                    'ISIC_0025170*', 'ISIC_0025193*', 'ISIC_0025208*', 
                    'ISIC_0025231*', 'ISIC_0025297*', 'ISIC_0025322*',
                    'ISIC_0034319*', 'ISIC_0034320*']:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern):
             os.remove(filename)
```

Note: I decreases the number of file names in the above code to better exemplify my idea. But as I said above, these are 2450 filenames.

Thanks for tips !

Comment: Perhaps use bash instead? And just run `rm ISIC_0024396*`, `rm <etc>` for each wildcard? This is if I'm understanding your question correctly and the format of your files

Comment: Why don't you simply handover the pattern to an external shell call? Should be way faster.

Comment: Really is this slow? It should be quite fast. If you're on a linux system, then use bash as TerryA says, or at least use os.system('rm <filename>'). os.remove is cross-platform, which may slow it down.

Comment: you could also speed things up by breaking once you've matched a pattern, as it stands you're testing every filename against every pattern so as a rough measure that would probably half the time taken to run.

Comment: @TerryA, The files are images of skin lesions. Total of 10015 images (.jpg), however there are repetitions of images by injury. Some lesions have more than one picture. And I need to have a dataset with just one image per lesion. In this way, it extracts a list with the name of all the images that are repeated and would like to erase them (images to be deleted have a total of 2545 files, with 7470 still remaining in the directory). My initial idea would be to automate the task a bit, because I might have to do it again. Would your idea be to delete all images directly? Even if it's 2545 files?

Comment: @JamesKent, I thought I'd do something like your idea. But since I do not have much programming experience, I could not think how to turn the idea into code.

Answer (score 1):

as stated in my comment above you are currently continuing to check for further matches after you find the first one, even though in this instance you won't and as the file has been removed it's not useful to, by breaking after a match:

```
os.chdir(directoryPath)
for filename in os.listdir('D:\Python\Jupyter\IP_Project\DataBase'):
    for pattern in ['ISIC_0024396*', 'ISIC_0024630*', 'ISIC_0024672*', 
                    'ISIC_0024700*', 'ISIC_0024771*', 'ISIC_0024834*', 
                    'ISIC_0024869*', 'ISIC_0024918*', 'ISIC_0024962*', 
                    'ISIC_0024998*', 'ISIC_0025005*', 'ISIC_0025040*', 
                    'ISIC_0025046*', 'ISIC_0025064*', 'ISIC_0025073*', 
                    'ISIC_0025112*', 'ISIC_0025152*', 'ISIC_0025168*', 
                    'ISIC_0025170*', 'ISIC_0025193*', 'ISIC_0025208*', 
                    'ISIC_0025231*', 'ISIC_0025297*', 'ISIC_0025322*',
                    'ISIC_0034319*', 'ISIC_0034320*']:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern):
             os.remove(filename)
             break # break now that we matched and move on to next file
```

you in theory reduce the time taken to process all of them by roughly half (assuming an even distribution of names per pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the tips.
For my problem specifically I can solve it in a much simpler way by removing the files directly as you indicated.

```
os.chdir(directory_path)
    for filename in repeated_images:
    os.remove(filename)
```